# Changing layer names when converting from WFS to Geopackage‏

Tags: ogr2ogr, geopackage

I want to convert WFS to  GeoPackage, everything is working fine but I need to change the name of each layer before converting to GeoPackage because the layer name has a special character ":" that throws an exception in the application that using the GeoPackage file.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you read the documentation of ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html you should find option `-nln`.

Comment: @user30184 yeah, I already read the documentation but I didn't know how to use this command with multiple layers.

Comment: That is not possible for multiple layers. Many other options in ogr2ogr are also per-layer. Converting a whole datastore with all layers into another datastore is a special use case. You must add and rename the layers one by one.

Comment: Thanks @user30184, appreciate it.

Comment: @user30184 Do you know a way to just replace the ":" with something else ?

Comment: I do not aware of such option. Some drivers like PostGIS https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html can "launder" table names but I am not sure if that applies to colons but anyway, it would not help you with GeoPackage.

Comment: @user30184 I mean before converting from WFS to GeoPackage just replace the character with something else.

Comment: I understood that and laundering does that automatically for some forbidden characters with some drivers. I believe that what you can do is just to write the new name as a whole into `-nln` parameter. Of course you can write a script and make it more automatic but that gets off-topic.

Comment: Thank you @user30184.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the ':' in the layer name "MODEE_MODEE_TEST1:Landmar_Infog_PILOT", then it's not so much of a 'special' character, but it means that "MODEE_MODEE_TEST1" is the (xml/gml) namespace/prefix of the layer type.

It is normal for xml/gml to have namespaces for elements, though off course it does not work if you use the whole typename as name for a table in another data format.

I googled the OGR WFS-driver docs, to see if you can maybe 'strip' the namespace in the gml output, but that seems not the case (others please correct me if I'm wrong).

Then, I looked at the GDAL GML driver docs (that is what the WFS is returning): https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html#creation-issues and that one has an option: STRIP_PREFIX Defaults to FALSE. Can be set to TRUE to avoid writing the prefix of the application target namespace in the GML file.
So I do not think you can use that as an option for the ogr2ogr WFS input, but maybe you an first request the data as GML, stripping the prefix from it, and THEN ogr2ogr into a geopackage? Note all this needs some scripting because you do this per layer.

But user30184 is stating rightfully, you can set a new name for a layer.

Some examples:

```
# this wfs service has a layer 'bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens' in which 'bestuurlijkegrenzen' is the prefix/namespace:
ogrinfo -geom=NO "WFS:https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bestuurlijkegrenzen/wfs" bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens

# writing it to geopackage your layername will 'bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens'
ogr2ogr -f gpkg output.gpkg "WFS:https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bestuurlijkegrenzen/wfs" bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens
# inspect:
ogrinfo output.gpkg
# 1: bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens (title: landsgrens)

# using -nln (new layer name, stripping the prefix):
ogr2ogr -f gpkg output.gpkg -nln landsgrens "WFS:https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/bestuurlijkegrenzen/wfs" bestuurlijkegrenzen:landsgrens
# inspect:
ogrinfo output.gpkg
# 1: landsgrens (title: landsgrens)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explaining, i will surely write a script for that.